# FileReader onprogress

Tags: javascript, file, typescript, filereader

**What I am trying to do?**
Upload a csv file and show the progress to the user as its being parsed.
Using csv-parse library as well as a FileReader to do the trick.

**The current behaviour**
The file uploads and everything is parsed but `reader.onprogress` returns 100% all the time. It doesn't seem to load in chunks. Using a debugger, i see that `event.loaded` is always the same as `event.total`. This is the case for ANY size file, whether its 400Kb or 40Mb - except in the 40Mb case it just takes a couple more seconds to show the 100. Code is below.

```
let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsText(this.file);

    reader.onload = () => {
        csvParse(reader.result, (err, data) => {
            for (let i: number = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                this.jsonData.push(data[i]);
            }
        });
    };

    reader.onprogress = (event) => {
        if (event.lengthComputable) {
            let progress: number = ((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
            console.log(progress);
        }
    };

    reader.onerror = function () {
       throw new Error("There was an issue reading the file." + reader.error);
    };
```

Comment: Are you running it on a local network? If so, did you try to throttle your connection (Chrome has this, just enable on the developer's console, network tab), you can simulate a slower network.

Comment: Yes chances are you just have a fast download speed.

Comment: No I haven't tried to throttle the network, that is a good suggestion. I'll try it now and see what it does.

Comment: So I throttled with 200Kb/s for download, 100Kb/s for upload with a latency of 5 ms for a 4Mb file, still got the same issue. `event.loaded` was the same as `event.total`

Comment: You're not downloading the file as you read it though, its already available before you call FileReader. Also I usually set up the handlers before I read the file, I don't know if that will make a difference though.

Comment: @Musa I see what you are saying. I thought that parsing the file itself had an `onprogress` but I guess not. But as for this issue, I ended up doing the parsing on the server. This way I am able to get an upload progress as the flow is: Upload file to server endpoint through xmlhttlrequest (has an onprogress), then do serverside actions and return results. Not exactly how I wanted it but i got something out of it.

Comment: @VedhaR Have you found the solution ? If yes can you please share here, hopefully this will help someone Even I am facing the same issue.